# Call a service from WaypointTaskExecutor plugin

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there
I am developing my own WaypointTaskExecutor plugin to be executed at waypoints (using nav2's waypoint_follower). Is there a way to call a service or at least publish some data on a topic, from within my plugin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397978/call-a-service-from-waypointtaskexecutor-plugin/) by [sdudiak01](https://answers.ros.org/users/99350/sdudiak01/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2022-03-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you check the `photo_at_waypoint` source code [there](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/main/nav2_waypoint_follower/plugins/photo_at_waypoint.cpp)? I think you can base your solution on it.

@stevemacenski wrote about it ([1](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/pull/1993#pullrequestreview-498015638), [2](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation.ros.org/issues/89), [3](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/pull/2015)) as an example plugin for processing.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sdudiak01](https://answers.ros.org/users/99350/sdudiak01/) on 2022-03-25**:
Thanks, that's exactly what i was looking for

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2022-03-28**:
Yay examples!